# Basic Authentication in REST WCF

Tags: wcf, restful-authentication

I have developed one REST WCF and would like to client will use it with basic Authentication, I have hosted this service in IIS 7.0 and disabled all authentication except Basic Authentication.

Now problem is that when call this service from any other application (in my case i am calling this from ruby command prompt) with Header "Basic bXlhZGRvbjpDcFplcUc5MzlHdDZQMEtD" although i was not able to authenticate this service.

Make it more simple , when i will access this service (.svc) from browser due to basic Authentication 
it will prompt to enter username & password , so which residential i need to pass here and to which credential i need to compare (weather i need to set in web.config or IIS)??

Thanks in Advance
Arun.

Comment: Basic authentication in IIS uses windows accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic authentication, IIS would always try to validate the userName & Password as a windows users (either local or domain user).

Dominick has created a Basic Http Authentication module which let's you use other credential stores with Basic Authentication.

http://www.leastprivilege.com/HTTPBasicAuthenticationAgainstNonWindowsAccountsInIISASPNETPart3AddingWCFSupport.aspx